# How do I JOIN tables when searching for duplicates

Tags: sql

I'm using the following query to locate dupees:

```
SELECT IDNumber
FROM t1
GROUP BY IDNumber
HAVING COUNT(IDNumber) > 1
```

Why is it when I attempt to join this table to another my result set comes back completely empty?

```
SELECT t1.IDNumber, t2.FieldName
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.IDNumber, t2.FieldName
HAVING COUNT(t1.IDNumber) > 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be two possibilities behind that :

First i would guess `t2.FieldName` isn't necessary to include in `group by` clause comparative to first version of query.

So, it could be :

```
SELECT t1.IDNumber
FROM t1 JOIN 
     t2 
     ON t2.ID = t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.IDNumber
HAVING COUNT(t1.IDNumber) > 1
```

Second would be, there is no data availability in `t2` comparative with `t1` table. If, none of them would not work, then you may need to edit the question with sample data & desired result that you want to express.